# How to handle C++ boost::filesystem functions that return string_type?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to compile the following snippet of code:

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
//Other includes snipped for brevity

boost::filesystem::path inPath("C:\\PathThatDoesNotExist");
std::cout << "Folder \'" << inPath.external_directory_string() 
  << "\' does not exist.";
```

and I'm getting this error:

> .\PathCheck.cpp(31) : error C2679:
>   binary '<<' : no operator found which
>   takes a right-hand operand of type
>   'const
>   boost::filesystem3::path::string_type'
>   (or there is no acceptable conversion)

My research so far tells me that this means the type is not known at compile time and that I might need a typedef? but I can't quite make that work in my head or in my code.  The external_directory_string() function is deprecated, so I'm also concerned that could be a factor somehow (I'm handling it with #define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATED).

Can someone explain string_type and recommend how to turn it into a std::string or char*?  I know there are other ways to get this information from a directory path, but I'd like to understand the issue anyway. :)

**RESOLVED:** I have v2 of the 1.44 boost libraries, but had "#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3" in my header (a co-worker using another version had added it).  If I comment this directive, my code compiles correctly.  Looks like we need to synchronize our libraries.

Comment: is there a missing variable name in the declaration (inPath) in the code?

Comment: You're right, thanks.  I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the mods below, your code compiles OK for me.  This applies with or without the `#define` you mentioned.

```
boost::filesystem::path inpath("C:\\PathThatDoesNotExist");
std::cout << "Folder \'" << inpath.external_directory_string() 
    << "\' does not exist.";
```

What version of Boost, and what compiler are you using?

I am on Boost 1.44, Visual C++ Express 2010.  `external_directory_string` appears to return `std::string` for me.

EDIT:
However, when I explicitly set the Boost Filesystem version like this, I get your error:

```
#   define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3
```

The default version for me on VS 2010 is 2, so I would investigate why `boost/filesystem/path.hpp` is setting this to 3 on your build.

From the Boost docs (1.45):

> This is Version 2 of the Filesystem library.
>
> Version 3, a major revision with many
>   new and improved features is also
>   available, but breaks some existing
>   code.

Sounds to me like if you get your build back to v2 you will be on more solid ground.

Comment: I am on Boost 1.44 also, using Visual Studio Team System 2008 (development edition).

Comment: @Ennael - that's odd.  Perhaps you could update your code to the version that actually fails.  There are syntax errors in the snippet posted, as noted.

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake typing my inPath declaration as a local one (my original is a member of the class).  I fixed that, as well as my escape character and cut-paste-compiled, to verify.  I'm still getting the same error.  Odd that you wouldn't be on the same version... will do some other checking to see what could be different.

Comment: It's worth noting that in my case the namespace is `filesystem2`, not `filesystem3` (see your warning error).  Are you explicitly requesting version 3?

Comment: That's it, exactly.  The #define in your edit was in my header file.  I think my co-worker must be using a different version of boost, so I guess that's something we need to work out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The boost::filesystem::path typedefs external_string_type to std::string (see here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/filesystem/path.hpp), which would suggest the problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: It seems I was using http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/boost/filesystem/v3/path.hpp whereas I needed to be using http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/boost/filesystem/v2/path.hpp.  Looks like we need to decide on one version of the boost libraries.  Thanks!